# HighCharts does not display tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

Well actually I'm starting using jquery and highcharts, the problem is that the highchart does not show the quantity of a bar in a tooltip.

This is my code.

```js
                   function pobox() {
                   var poBox = JSON;
                   $(function() {
                     $('#container').highcharts({
                       chart: {
                         type: 'column'
                       },
                       title: {
                         text: 'Cantidad Mensual de paquetes POBOX'
                       },
                       subtitle: {
                         text: 'fuente: BD'
                       },
                       xAxis: {
                         categories: [
                           'Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'
                         ],
                         crosshair: true
                       },
                       yAxis: {
                         min: 0,
                         title: {
                           text: 'Ventas'
                         }
                       },
                       legend: {
                         enabled: false
                       },
                       plotOptions: {
                         column: {
                           dataLabels: {
                             enabled: true,
                             formatter: function() {

                               return this.point.custom;
                             }
                           }
                         }
                       },
                       tooltip: {
                         crosshairs: true,
                         formatter: function() {
                           return '<strong>Value: </strong>' + this.point.custom + 'units' + '<br/><strong>Percent: </strong>' + this.y;
                         }
                       },
                       series: poBox
                     });
                   });
                   }
                   }
                   });
                   }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Start Graphic one -->




<button type="button" class="button" onclick="pobox()">Enviar</button>
<div id="container" style="width:90%; height:250px;">
```

I received a JSON as parameters. But when the mouse hover a bar, how to display the values of the bar.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with an example of the data you are using?

Comment: How your data does it look like? Could you post your series object as json ?